# join different regex possibilities into one

Tags: regex, sed, regex-group

Is it possible to make the following regex-es into one?

```
cat file.txt | \ 
sed 's/\tNULL\t/\t\\N\t/g' | \
sed 's/^NULL\t/\\N\t/g' | \
sed 's/\tNULL$/\t\\N/g' | \
sed 's/^NULL$/\\N/g''
```

Maybe another thing to add, this is going over billions of rows a month so performance is a consideration.

**Solutions benchmark**
Thank you all for the suggestions, `perl` run the fastest for me. In case you wondered:

```
[/tmp]$ time cat /tmp/result_w_null.txt > /dev/null
real    0m0.045s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.042s
[/tmp]$ time cat /tmp/result_w_null.txt | sed 's/\<NULL\>/\\N/g' > /dev/null
real    0m5.843s
user    0m2.472s
sys     0m3.852s
[/tmp]$ time cat /tmp/result_w_null.txt | sed 's/\tNULL\t/\t\\N\t/g' | sed 's/^NULL\t/\\N\t/g' | sed 's/\tNULL$/\t\\N/g' | sed 's/^NULL$/\\N/g' > /dev/null
real    0m7.078s
user    0m7.148s
sys     0m4.963s

#Suggestions:
[/tmp]$ time cat /tmp/result_w_null.txt | awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="NULL") $i="\\N"}1' > /dev/null
real    0m20.196s
user    0m14.876s
sys     0m7.145s
[/tmp]$ time cat /tmp/result_w_null.txt | awk -v RS='(^|[\t\n])NULL(\tNULL)*([\t\n]|$)' '{ gsub(/NULL/, "\\N", RT); ORS=RT} 1' > /dev/null
real    0m10.611s
user    0m8.743s
sys     0m3.754s
[/tmp]$ time cat /tmp/result_w_null.txt | sed -E ':a; s/(\t|^)NULL(\t|$)/\1\\N\2/g; ta' > /dev/null
real    0m9.673s
user    0m5.723s
sys     0m5.678s
[/tmp]$ time cat /tmp/result_w_null.txt | perl -pe 's/(?:\t|^)\KNULL(?=\t|$)/\\N/g' > /dev/null
real    0m4.452s
user    0m3.237s
sys     0m2.288s
```

Comment: `/(?:^|\t)NULL(?:$|\t)/` would probably o it. What is the purpose of `\t\\N\t/g`? Is this specific to some programming language?

Comment: `\t` - tab. `\\N` - represent `null` in different format for some data loading tool. I kept it simple and basic to what I need to not getting out of scope.

Comment: Right, you may use `'s/(\t|^)NULL(\t|$)/\1\\N\2/g'` - but if you are using `sed` and you have consecutive matches, like `NULL    NULL  NULL`, you need to run it in a loop.

Comment: You're afraid of being out of scope so you ask a question with no scope? The `s/` and `/\t\\N\t/g` are really confusing because a regex starts and ends with a forward slash traditionally so if you use a slash in the middle then it should be escaped like so `\/`. Modifiers like `/gmi` go at the end so unless you elaborate on what this tool is then you might not get relevant answers.

Comment: Oh it's `sed`? Then Wiktor's suggestion should work.

Comment: You'd almost certainly be better off using awk as you appear to be trying to deal with tab-separated fields and input with fields is what awk was designed to handle. If you post concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/(\t|^)NULL(\t|$)/\1\\N\2/g;'
```

If there can be consecutive matches

```sh
sed -E ':a; s/(\t|^)NULL(\t|$)/\1\\N\2/g; ta'
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/J972mV).

The POSIX ERE regex matches

- `(\t|^)` - Capturing group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern): a tab or start of string
- `NULL` - a literal string
- `(\t|$)` - Capturing group 2 (`\2` in the replacement pattern): a tab or end of string.

For consecutive matches, you need to match in a loop, by setting a label (`:a`) and then branching to it using `ta`. This is a way to work around the lack of lookahead support that would allow checking for the trailing tab without *consuming* it. In Perl, you would use

```sh
perl -pe 's/(?:\t|^)\KNULL(?=\t|$)/\\N/g'
```

where

- `(?:\t|^)` - a non-capturing group matching a tab or start of string
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `NULL` - a literal string
- `(?=\t|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires a tab or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: thank you. maybe you can explain why consecutive `NULL` in a row make a different? Usually it doesn't.

Comment: Also, how is the performance of the `:a` and `ta` method? Is it the same as the four `sed`s ? I going over billions of rows

Comment: @Nir Use `awk` or `perl` then. `sed` with `:a...ta` is usually slow.

Comment: You don't really need `:a...ta`, just perform the substitution twice: `sed -E 's/(\t|^)NULL(\t|$)/\1\\N\2/g; s/(\t|^)NULL(\t|$)/\1\\N\2/g;'`. @Nir the reason you need to do it twice is that given `XaXaX` execution `s/XaX/g'` will use up the first 2 `X`s in the first match, leaving the trailing `aX` for the second attempt at `XaX` to match. Try it.

Comment: I will try that, with performance comparison to perl and awk ! thanks

Comment: perl is the fastest, so I mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Nir Glad it worked for you. So, was the `perl` version fast enough?

Comment: It is not worst then current solution, even a bit faster! so, I can't complain. however, of course I would love it if we can make it much more closer to the time of `time cat /tmp/result_w_null.txt > /dev/null`. You think such thing is possible?

Comment: @Nir I do not think so.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` might be easier to comprehend for this usage:

```sh
awk '
  BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}
  {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      if ($i == "NULL")
        $i = "\\N"
    print
  }
' file.txt
```

Or, one-liner-ized

```sh
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="NULL") $i="\\N"}1' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Your welcome sir and many congrats for well earned 200K repo, cheers and happy sharing sir :)

Comment: working! I will test the performance on a large scale of result and report back!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate gnu-awk solution:

```sh
cat file

abc   NULL  foo
NULL  bar
xyz   NULL
pqr   mnop
NULL
```

Using `gnu-awk` with a custom `RS`:

```sh
awk -v RS='(^|[\t\n])NULL(\tNULL)*([\t\n]|$)' '{
gsub(/NULL/, "\\N", RT); ORS=RT} 1' file

abc   \N    foo
\N    bar
xyz   \N
pqr   mnop
\N
```

Comment: from testing this replace only once in a row